# Error Viewing file on HiGlass

Tags: visualization, genomics

I am implementing hi-glass python on Jupyter, and upon running the test data code

```
from higlass.client import View, Track
from higlass.tilesets import cooler

ts1 = cooler('../data/Dixon2012-J1-NcoI-R1-filtered.100kb.multires.cool')
tr1 = Track('heatmap', tileset=ts1)
view1 = View([tr1])
display, server, viewconf = higlass.display([view1])

display
```

I get the error message stating:

```
Error Retrieving tileset info: http://localhost:60501/spi/v1
```

Please advise on the correcting. The code above has been copied from the [HiGlass webpage](https://docs.higlass.io/jupyter.html).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you "set up a temporary server" as the guide suggests ? It doesn't provide how to do it, but presumably it should be easy to do

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the authors of HiGlass. Sorry you're getting that error. I just tried it out in a fresh environment and it worked for me. Just one thing is missing in the docs which is that you need to do `import higlass`.

Here's what I did to set up my environment:

```
conda create --name test-bi python=3.6
source activate test-bi
```

The rest is from the docs:

```
pip install jupyter higlass-python
jupyter nbextension install --py --sys-prefix --symlink higlass
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix higlass
jupyter notebook
```

It looks like either you or somebody else added a bug report here: https://github.com/higlass/higlass-python/issues/29

I'll respond and continue the conversation there.

Also, there's a repository full of examples from the HiGlass SciPy presentation here: https://github.com/higlass/scipy19